# Ionic tags not rendering after $scope changes

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to display a form that may be different depending on the user. So, after logging in I request the data and receive a JSON with the inputs that should be displayed:

```
{"campos":[
    {"field":"tec","name_es":"Tecnico","required":1,"tipo":"autodropdown","placeholder_es":null},
    {"field":"horas","name_es":"Horas","required":1,"tipo":"input","placeholder_es":null},
    {"field":"fechaEntrada","name_es":"Fecha Entrada","required":0,"tipo":"datetime","placeholder_es":"0"},
    {"field":"fechaSalida","name_es":"Fecha Salida","required":0,"tipo":"datetime","placeholder_es":null},
    {"field":"observaciones","name_es":"Observaciones","required":0,"tipo":"textarea","placeholder_es":null},
    {"field":"facturable","name_es":"Facturable","required":0,"tipo":"onoff","placeholder_es":null}
]}
```

On my Controller I process this data and get this HTML as a result:

```
<label class="item item-input" id="horas">
    <span class="input-label">Horas</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Horas" value="" ng-model="user.horas" required>
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Fecha Entrada</span>
    <input type="date">
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Fecha Salida</span>
    <input type="date">
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Observaciones</span>
    <textarea rows="6" placeholder=""></textarea>
</label>
<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm">Facturable</ion-toggle>
```

After this I assign the output HTML to the `$scope` using `<form ng-bind-html="output" class="list"></form>`

My problem is that the HTML doesn't renders correctly, I'm getting this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image: expected result]

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, the form renders fine on first go, then fails to render correctly after one is submitted and $scope changes?

Comment: not exactly. I build the form in the controller then change the $scope to render it on the view. The problem is that the ionic directives doesn't render because the view has already been rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that the view was already rendered when the controller was called.

Use this directive instead :

```
.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Controller :

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.varname = '<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm">Facturable</ion-toggle>';
});
```

Use it in your views this way:

```
<div dynamic="varname"></div>
```

I found the same problem in Ionic forums, check this for more information:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recompile-ng-bind-html/15507

Comment: Thanks David! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comments that:

> The problem is that the ionic directives doesn't render because the view has already been rendered.

What you can do is wrap your functionality inside `$ionicView.beforeEnter`. That way you can build the form in the controller and then change the $scope to render it in the view before actually entering it.  It's pretty straight forward.

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data){
       // handle form change inside here
    });
}
```

Here is [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) on `$ionicView.beforeEnter`. There are other variations of handling what to do before/after view change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sam5487, but unfortunately it doesn't works.